# ADFS integration with java

Tags: adfs, adfs3.0

How to integrate **ADFS3.0** with login page designed in **JSF**?.

Possible to use our custom login pages in ADFS?

Answer (score 1):

ADFS requires clients to use the WS-Federation, SAML 2.0 or (for web API only) OAuth as the protocol.

So you need a client side stack that uses one of these.

SAML stacks [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

[This](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-jsf-applications-with-spring-boot/) may help (Spring is one of the stacks above).

No - the login page is served by ADFS.